# Does Parrot have a multi-threaded parallel garbage collector?

Tags: raku, parrot, rakudo

My question is about the garbage collector in the Parrot Virtual Machine ( http://www.parrot.org ).

Is it multi-threaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parrot itself is multi-threaded, it even scales linearily up to the available physical CPU cores, and it's GC supports multiple threads properly, i.e. without any locks on data structures *(which is BTW a major benefit over the MoarVM or JVM backends which use tradional locks on hashes, PMC's and arrays all over)*, but the GC itself does not run in seperate threads. 
The GC only runs in the master thread and is a simple Mark&Sweep (i.e. *"stop the world"*) tri-color generational GC.

The GC threads design overview is described here: http://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/day-11-parrot-threads/ and in detail by the implementor here: http://niner.name/Hybrid_Threads_for_the_Parrot_VM.pdf

But note that parrot only supports threads (i.e. tasks) being created from the master interpreter, not from other tasks (threads), the threadpool is pre-initialized at startup and managed automatically. Only the owner may write data via prioritized scheduled little proxy-writer tasks. Technically you may create tasks from other tasks, but it will cause leaks.

To other threads non-atomic data is visible via read-only proxy objects. The high-level language compiler needs to create these writer tasks for you. See the `examples/threads/` directory.

Comment: Now that a proper answer has arrive I delete my wrong answer. Thanks :)